# ES6, REACT error message I do not understand

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the next code:

```
 close = () => {
     this.setState({ open: false });
     this.props.onUpdate(this.props.defaultValue);
 }
```

But I am getting the next error message:

```
ERROR in ./ui/usersModule/scripts/usersTable.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: 


 Error: Unexpected token (232:8)

  230 |   }
  231 |
> 232 |   close = () => {
      |         ^
  233 |     this.setState({ open: false });
  234 |     this.props.onUpdate(this.props.defaultValue);
  235 |   }
```

I saw that it compiles on the original code but for some reason it does not compile in my machine. I need to call it from:

```
onClick={ this.close }
```

Why could be my error? is there another way to call that  close  function?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the typical webpack+babel setup to compile ES6+ code, you need [`babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Install the module, and add this under `babel` to your `package.json`, or your `.babelrc`:

```
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
```

Comment: how could this be done at webpack.config.js?